# ReactJS: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Пользуюсь webpack для сборки проекта. Конфигурация вот:

```
'use strict';

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry:   {
        main: "./main",
        common: "./common"
    },
    output:  {
        path: __dirname + (NODE_ENV == "development" ? "/www/js-dev/" : "/www/js/"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module:  {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query:
                {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    watch:   NODE_ENV == "development",
    devtool: NODE_ENV == "development" ? "source-map" : null,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
            LANG: JSON.stringify("en")
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "common",
            minChunks: 2
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    }
};

if (NODE_ENV == "production") {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                drop_console: true
            }
        })
    );
}
```

При этом ошибку вызывает следующий синтаксис:

```
class Footer extends React.Component
{
    //...

    handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

    //...
}
```

Что сделать, чтоб все генерировалось нормально?

Вот такой код ошибок не вызывает, но и не работает:

```
class Footer extends React.Component
{
    //...

    handleChange (event, index, value)
    {
         this.setState({value});
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: ну это и есть синтаксическая ошибка во втором коде который у вас есть. А с чего вы взяли что не работает последний? насколько я вижу, он работает. У вас должен быть в конструкторе объявлен `this.state = {value: 'someValue'};`. И как вы пытаетесь вызвать `handleChange`?

Comment: Код, в котором, как вы пишете, есть синтаксическая ошибка взят отсюда: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toolbar 

Последний вариант, действительно, работает. не знаю, почему я подумал, что нет (

Comment: Хм, как ни странно парсер не ругается на второй код, но он и не работает. Но я и первый раз встречаю такое написание. Возможно нужен какой то плагин либо определенная версия `babel` для его работы. Я использую `stage-1` + плагин для декораторов. Но раньше у меня это вызывало ошибку, сейчас нет, но и не работает))